# Rectangle getting drawn in the wrong spot

Tags: java, jframe, drawrectangle

I am creating a game inside a `JFrame` (854 x 480). I am trying to draw a `Rectangle` in the upper right hand corner of the screen. like so:

```
int x, y;
Rectangle rect;

public Foo() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    
    rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 63, 27);
}

....

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
}
```

But when I do this, the box gets drawn off the screen (x co-ords are right, but y co-ords too high :

[image: Rectangle off screen]

When I change the y co-ords to 27 (the height of the rectangle), it moves down to where I want it to go:

[image: Rectangle on screen]

Any idea why this is happening? Or how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you override the paint(..) method of your JFrame? The coordinates seem to be in the coordinate space of the window/JFrame, where 0/0 includes the non-client area (the close box, title bar and so on).

You should create a separate component and add this to the content pane of your main frame - just a very tiny example - note that I am using paintComponent(..):

```
public static class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Float(8,8, 128, 64));
    }

}
```

Add to JFrame content pane (use default or custom LayoutManager):

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public MyFrame() {
       ...
       // since JDK 1.4 you do not need to use JFrame.getContentPane().add(..)
       this.add(new MyPanel());
    }
}
```

This should do the trick. [Here's the corresponding section of the Java SE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/problems.html).

Comment: No this is a new class, in the main method my paint method is calling this draw method like this: `foo.draw(g);`

Answer (score 1):

This is because the JFrames co-ordinates are starting at the top left corner including the title bar. You need to add the height of the title bar to your y co-ordinate to make it show in the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the Rect in a JPanel.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
this.add(panel) //Add the panel to the frame and draw from there
                //Provided the class extends a JFrame
```